# Event Listener - push method issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a simple event listener with some conditionals and weirdly the array playerGuess replaces the array allPlayerGuesses, instead of be pushed, as intended. Someone can tell what I am missing?

```
//global variables
guessX = document.querySelector("#guess-x-input"),
guessY = document.querySelector("#guess-y-input"),
boardSize, /*defined by user. must be between 7 and 12 */
playerGuess = [],
allPlayerGuesses = [],


fireButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var sameGuess = false,          


    if (guessX.value === undefined || guessX.value < 1 || guessX.value > boardSize || guessY.value === undefined || guessY.value < 1 || guessY.value > boardSize ) {
        alert("Wrong coordinates!"); 
    } else if (allPlayerGuesses.length === 0) {        
        playerGuess[0] = guessX.value - 1;
        playerGuess[1] = guessY.value - 1;
        allPlayerGuesses.push(playerGuess);            
    } else if (allPlayerGuesses.length !== 0) {               
        playerGuess[0] = guessX.value - 1;        
        playerGuess[1] = guessY.value - 1; 

        for (var i = 0; i < allPlayerGuesses.length; i++) {
            if (playerGuess[0] === allPlayerGuesses[i][0] && playerGuess[1] === allPlayerGuesses[i][1] ) {
                alert("Coordinate already uncovered. Select another!");
                sameGuess = true;                
            } 
        }

        if (!sameGuess) { 
            playerGuess[0] = guessX.value - 1;
            playerGuess[1] = guessY.value - 1;
            allPlayerGuesses.push(playerGuess);
        }        
    }

    if (board[playerGuess[0]][playerGuess[1]] === "bp") {
        document.querySelector(".ship-cell-" + playerGuess[0] + "-" + playerGuess[1]).classList.remove("hid");
    } else {
        document.querySelector(".miss-cell-" + playerGuess[0] + "-" + playerGuess[1]).classList.remove("hid");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share How allPlayerGuesses is declared? Also the playerGuess ?

Comment: **Declare your variables**. The fact that you don't _need_ to, doesn't mean that you don't _have_ to. Probably that has to do with the problem. Show the full code or create a fiddler to verify.

Comment: of course! It´s a snippet of a Battleship game code, with around 400 lines, but i will edit the original post, including all thyhe variables that should help. Thank you, so much!

Comment: Yes, Gabriel. You´re right too, indeed! The concerning variables was declared, but they need to be reinicialised when the event is triggered. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. 
when you do allPlayerGuesses.push(playerGuess), it not only inserts it to the allPlayerGuesses but also replaces the existing values of playerGuess in the array. You can verify this by checking length of allPlayerGuesses. This would create duplicate entries in the allPlayerGuesses.

The solution to this would be initialize playerGuess everytime you enter in the click event.

```
fireButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   playerGuess = [];
   // your other code...
});
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Great, Chetan! Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: No worries. I am glad that I could help.